# Google Maps Marker To Change OnClick

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a google map integrated into my website. I have 2 google map markers inside the map.

On mouseover and mouseout, both these marker images change as I desire. That is all working.

I have it setup that once a marker is clicked, the page url changes and reloads. This is all working fine.

My problem is that I want my google marker icon to change also when the marker is clicked.

So to make it simple.

- Marker A = Clicked.

  New Page Loads From Marker A Being Clicked.

  Marker A should change Icon on new page.

I hope I have explained this is a straight forward way. Here is my current code.

```
  var iconBase = window.location.origin +   '/assets/images/map_red_small_full_icon.png';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: {lat: 54.339549, lng: -5.266286},
 map: map,
 icon: iconBase
});  

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', '/locations#marker1');
    marker.setIcon(iconBasetitle);
    location.reload();
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

So the url is changed based on when the marker is clicked. The New page loads but the marker does not change.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. How does the "new" page set the updated icon for the marker?

Comment: @geocodezip: *«How does the "new" page set the updated icon»* That looks to be the question... It think the question is complete... Maybe not verifiable, but complete.

Comment: Not much more I can give you in terms of information, always appreciate the downpost for a genuine question...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `iconBasetitle` is the new icon, when the marquer has been clicked.

Since the page reloads, the whole script reloads too.
So your marquer is resetted to it's original state.

You only have to add something in the script to change the icon based on the hash you added in the URL.

Something like this will probably do:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
    if(hash=="marker1"){
        marker.setIcon(iconBasetitle);
    }
}
```